# How to grab the parent url from an iFrame using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iframe

My scenario is I have a page name `UserMain.aspx` and in this page I have 2 sections (ie2 `IFrame`s). Now from one of the `IFrame` pages I want to get `parentUrl` (ie `www.xyz/UserMain.aspx`). I have tried the `Request.url` but it's giving the url of `IFrame`, how to get the `parentUrl`?

Both `IFrame` and parent pages are on same domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The different windows and iframes only exist in the browser, the server code has no means to navigate between them.

In clientscript you can access the URL of the parent window, given of course that the page and iframe is from the same domain:

```
var parentUrl = window.parent.location.href;
```

Comment: so thr's no way to do it from backend code i.e c# code.. client script is the only way.. thnx

Comment: @Fosterz: You can set your code behind variable from your javascript; for instance like `<%strParentUrl%> = parentUrl`.

Comment: @KMan: What posseses you to think that something like that would work?

Answer (score 12):

You could try using the following. I tried it in one of my solutions but it was not quite what I needed. Maybe it will help you

```
Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.ToString();
```

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` returns the iframe location in my razor script

Answer (score 1):

```
string UrlBrowser= Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this through client-side script using `window.parent.location.href`. This works in case you have an iframe at first level inside a loaded page. If you have more levels of hierarchy, like iframe within iframe ... then you can use `window.top.location.href`.

window.top always gets you to the topmost parent window.

Comment: i want to save that parentUrl to a session, so i want to grab parentUrl from c# code, how to do that ?

Comment: @Fosterz - As others have suggested, you might not be able to get that info from server side, however, you can have a hidden control (like textbox or label), set the value for them through javascript and then you can get that value from your server side by getting value from that hiddencontrol.

Comment: "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" is giving the current URL not the parent url.